# Meteor event handler : target.<name> not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

My template is as below:

```
    <template name="dashboard">
<div>
        <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#state" style="text-align:center;font-size:120%" class="register list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">Register Your bills</a>
        <div id="MainMenu">
        <div id="state" class="collapse">
{{ #each Utilities}}
        <a href="#{{.}}" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">{{.}}</a>
        <div class="collapse" id={{.}}>
    {{ #each Billers . }}
                    <a href="#{{st_id}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse">{{state}}<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="collapse offset list-group-submenu" id={{st_id}}>

                    ==> Adding event handler for this element <a href="#" class="list-group-item billername" name="billername" data-toggle="collapse">{{name}}</a>

                    </div>
    {{ /each }}
        </div>
{{ /each }}
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</template>
```

In the above HTML, I've added a pointer to which element I'm adding a event handler to. This 'a' class element is part of a hierarchical list, and is 2 levels below the root of the hierarchy. That is, it appears on the page when two higher level links are clicked.

The event handler code is as below:

```
Template.dashboard.events({
    "click .billername":function(event){
        console.log(event.currentTarget.billername);
    }
});
```

`billername` is the `name` attribute of the  element. However, `console.log` prints `undefined`. I don't understand why this is happening..

**Update:**
The method mentioned in the comment below worked for me. But what is the reason the method above didn't work? That is the method documented by Meteor and numerous other tutorials..I was planning to use `event.target.billername.value` as suggested everywhere, but `event.target.billername` itself was `undefined`

Comment: Try `event.currentTarget.innerText`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that saved me. I don't understand though why existing meteor documented methods don't work

Comment: This is not a Meteor issue at all, just an issue with what attributes various DOM elements have.